# Get profile picture on Instagram Basic Display API

Tags: api, instagram

I am currently using the new [Instagram API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api) since the previous one is closed the registration, I can only get the ID, user and amount of post, is there any other way to get the user's profile picture?

Answer (score -1):

There are two Instagram platform, which is IG Business API and IG Basic Display API. The document you mentioned is Basic Display, and currently, you are only able to get medis (with suitable permission), the IG team has not extended for user profile picture, yet.